# Почему 97% нагрузка на CPU при использовании pygame на Linux?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.5, pygame

```
    # Скелет  проекта
import pygame
# import random
# import time

WIDTH = 360
HEIGHT = 480
FPS = 30

# Define useful colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
# Инициализация пайгейма и создание окна
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Project 404')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()



# GAME LOOP

running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)    

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check for closing the window
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # keep loop running at the right speed

    # Process inputs (events)

    # Update
    # Draw / Render
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    # After drawing everything flip display.
    pygame.display.flip()

# pygame.quit()
```

Что не так в коде ? На **Windows** этот же код потребляет всего **12%** CPU.

Comment: И правда нагрузка, странное явление

Comment: Потому что не передаётся управление на другие процессы или нитки? Где-то в коде у вас должен быть sleep able код, а его по всей видимости нет, вот и переключается задача редко, когда успевает "проскочить" между критическими секциями.

Comment: Ошибка в питоне, ошибка в SDL, обновляйтесь, читайте баги на их баг трекерах... я бы с этого начал.

Comment: @0andriy даже если заменить `clock.tick(FPS)` на `time.sleep(1)`, всё равно жрёт проц, я это первым делом попробовал

Comment: @stackflow https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/331 , на текущий момент баг открыт.

Comment: Убунта? Я не помню точно, но на убунте у меня были баги с events конкретные. На fedora все нормально работало.